# Tweepy PHPMyAdmin code keeps breaking

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

so I've been using Tweepy to run my Python code to scrape certain movie titles and store them in my PHPmyAdmin database using the nohup terminal statement to keep it running. The first two weeks the code only broke once, but ever since it's been breaking down more and more, now it's gotten to the point where the code stops running multiple times a day.

```
import tweepy 
import time, json, datetime
import pprint as p
import pymysql, sys
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import datetime
import sys

consumer_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.count = 0
        self.api = api
        super(tweepy.StreamListener, self).__init__()

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print 'Error: ' + repr(status_code)
        return False

    def on_data(self, tweet):
        tweet = json.loads(tweet)

        try:
            if tweet['created_at']:
                ts = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.strptime(tweet['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')) 
            else:
                ts = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

            data = (tweet['id_str'],tweet['user']['name'],ts ,tweet['in_reply_to_user_id_str'],tweet['in_reply_to_status_id_str'],tweet['favorite_count'],tweet['retweet_count'],tweet['retweeted'],tweet['text'],tweet['lang'],tweet['user']['location'],tweet['user']['time_zone'])

            cur.execute("INSERT INTO AllMovieTweets (id_str,user_name,created_at, in_reply_to_user_id_str,in_reply_to_status_id_str,favorite_count,retweet_count,retweeted,text,lang,user_location,time_zone) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", data)
            conn.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print "error in stream listener ",e
            print data

        return True

    def on_timeout(self):
        return True # Don't kill the stream

try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='xxxxxxxx', port=xxxx, user='xxxxxx', passwd='xxxxxxxx', db='xxxxxxxxxx', charset='utf8')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    l = StreamListener()
    streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=l)
    setTerms = [ 'graceofmonaco', 'grace of monaco', 'need for speed', 'needforspeed', 'NFSmovie', 'muppets most wanted', 'muppetsmovie2', 'muppetsmostwanted', 'muppets movie', 'muppets film', 'divergent', 'badwords', 'bad words movie', 'bad words film', 'badwordsmovie', 'noah', 'noahmovie', 'a haunted house', 'ahhmovie', 'ahauntedhousemovie', 'ahauntedhouse', 'captain america', 'captainamerica', 'winter soldier', 'wintersoldier', 'domhemingway', 'dom hemingway']      
    streamer.filter(track = setTerms)


except Exception as e:
    print "error",e
    sys.exit()
```

The error I have gotten most of the times this past week was:

**error in stream listener  'created_at'
error local variable 'data' referenced before assignment**

This is why I already put in the try and else statement with real time in there because I thought the error meant there was a format error with the time from time to time so if I got it to store time.strftime instead then it wouldn't break down but unfortunately that didn't help. Does anyone have any suggestions what is causing this error? Could it be a fault with Tweepy or is there an obvious bug in my code?

Comment: Well, for one you `print data` in the Exception and if the exception occurs before `data` is actually defined in the `try` block it will cause your local variable referenced before assignment error.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it a bit more I had a similar problem that was caused by tweets containing unicode characters. Try adding ` # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the top of your program and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I looked it up and I've added                        #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- to the top of my code, I will respond back to let you know how that worked out. Should I move the print data part to somewhere else?

Comment: Hmm, why not just print it after you declare it instead of print it only when an exception occurs? Unless you want to keep the behavior of only printing if an exception formatting your tweet has occurred.

Comment: Well, it just broke again and it was the same error code "error in stream listener  'created_at'
error local variable 'data' referenced before assignment" so that unfortunately didn't work. Any other suggestions/solutions?

Comment: Oh, I did put in another print statement for created_at after I declare it for a while to print it to the nohup.out file. But I took it out again bc the file got so big and I didn't really get much from it. When I did that,  when the code broke down it said: "error IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)"

Comment: Try commenting out the try:except statement and parse the tweet without handling any exception to see if you can get a stack trace and find out what is really going on.

Comment: Another idea: Could it be you reached the rate limit? [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#6861) may be sending you a rate limit message.

Comment: This is the error I got before the try except statement and the exception handler: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 776, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 654, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 436, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 306, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: That could be related to the link I posted above: "If there are more tweets that would match your criteria, you'll be streamed a rate limit message indicating how many tweets were not delivered." json.loads expects a string as an argument and Twitter may be sending you something nasty. Explicitly convert the tweet to a string (maybe print before parsing the JSON for debugging) and see if that gets you any further.